# How to use the counter as a variable extension in for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

This is my code

```
for ($m = 1; $m <= $j; $m++)
    {
        if ($_POST['item_id".$m."'] > 0)
        {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '$_POST['item_id".$m."']' WHERE PO = '$k'");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET Product_Name = '$_POST['item_name".$m."']' WHERE PO = '$k'");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET Quantity_Ordered = '$_POST['item_qty".$m."']' WHERE PO = '$k'");
        }
    }
```

But I get

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING
>   or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Also I tried

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '$_POST['item_qty$m']' WHERE PO = '$k'");
```

Get the same result.

Could someone help me? THanks >-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are not balanced properly.  Fixing them gives you this:

```
for ($m = 1; $m <= $j; $m++)
{
    if ($_POST["item_id".$m] > 0)
    {
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '" . $_POST["item_id".$m]   . "' WHERE PO = '$k'");
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET Product_Name = '" . $_POST["item_name".$m] . "' WHERE PO = '$k'");
       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET Quantity_Ordered = '" . $_POST["item_qty".$m]  . "' WHERE PO = '$k'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi the code does not return error, but it does not insert any data into db. I have tried `echo $_POST["item_id1"]; ` it returns the value I want.

Comment: I updated the answer, since I had copied and pasted ProductID incorrectly.  Note, the value of `$k` in `PO = '$k'` needs to be defined in order for this logic to work.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with that, but double check to ensure that is defined. Also, this can (and should) be combined into a single query.

Comment: ok i just fixed, thanks for helping :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the variable inside the MySQL query:

From

```
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '$_POST['item_id".$m."']' WHERE PO = '$k'");
```

to

```
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '". $_POST['item_id".$m."'] . "' WHERE PO = '$k'");
```

And the same for the others. All together:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '". $_POST['item_id".$m."'] . "' WHERE PO = '$k'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '". $_POST['item_name".$m."'] ."' WHERE PO = '$k'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '". $_POST['item_qty".$m."'] ."' WHERE PO = '$k'");
```

Comment: Hi the code does not return error, but it does not insert any data into db. I have tried echo $_POST["item_id1"]; it returns the value I want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that?

```
for ($m = 1; $m <= $j; $m++) {
    $item = $_POST['item_id' . $m];
    if ($item > 0) {
        $itemName = $_POST['item_name' . $m];
        $itemQty = $_POST['item_qty' . $m];
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '" . $item . "' WHERE PO = '" . $k . "'");
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '" . $itemName . "' WHERE PO = '" . $k . "'");
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Orders SET ProductID = '" . $itemQty . "' WHERE PO = '" . $k . "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi same, the code does not return error, but it does not insert any data into db. I have tried echo $_POST["item_id1"]; it returns the value I want

Comment: show me please: `var_dump($_POST);` before for loop.